# не работает транслитерация python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

```
alph = {"Q":"q","W":"w","E":"e","R":"r","T":"t","Y":"y","U":"u","I":"i","O":"o","P":"p","A":"a","S":"s","D":"d","F":"f","G":"g","H":"h","J":"j","K":"k","L":"l","Z":"z","X":"x","C":"c","V":"v","B":"b","N":"n","M":"m","Й":"й","Ц":"ц","У":"у","К":"к","Е":"е","Н":"н","Г":"г","Ш":"ш","Щ":"щ","З":"з","Х":"х","Ё":"е","Ф":"ф","Ы":"ы","В":"в","А":"а","П":"п","Р":"р","О":"о","Л":"л","Д":"д","Ж":"ж","Э":"э","Я":"я","Ч":"ч","С":"с","М":"м","И":"и","Т":"т","Ь":"ь","Б":"б","Ю":"ю","й":"j","ц":"c","у":"u","к":"k","е":"e","н":"n","г":"g","ш":"sh","щ":"shch","з":"z","х":"h","ф":"f","ы":"y","в":"v","а":"a","п":"p","р":"r","о":"o","л":"l","д":"d","ж":"zh","э":"e","я":"ya","ч":"ch","с":"s","м":"m","и":"i","т":"t","б":"b","ю":"yu"," ":"","ь":"","Ъ":"ь","ъ":"",".":"",",":"","!":"","?":"","'":"",'"':'',"-":""}
for a in range(0,len(alph)-1):
    try:
        text = text.replace(text[a],alph[text[a]])
    except:
        pass
```

Когда вводишь латиницу то все работает, а кириллицу он так и оставляет. В чем проблема?

Comment: Скорее всего проблемы с кодировкой файла.

Comment: какую поставить?

Comment: utf-8. Вообще кодировка файла должна совпадать с кодировкой локали. Проверил ваш код и он работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка вот в чем: `a` у вас "индекс" по словарю `alph` (точнее `a`, изменяется от 0 до размера словаря), а применяете вы его как индекс по переменной `text`. Т.к. словарь может оказаться длиннее чем входная строка, то у вас будет вылетать ошибка выхода за границы строки. Вместо того чтобы с ней разобраться вы ее подавили с помощью пустого `except`. **Так делать не нужно, тупым подавлением исключения вы только усложняете себе поиск ошибок.**

Второе: похоже что вам нужно все буквы привести к нижнему регистру, русские буквы транслитеровать, убрать все символы. Проще сначала привести все к нижнему регистру (это делается одним вызовом метода), убрать все символы, только потом проводить транслитерацию. Пример:

```
text = "Йцукен / Qwerty"
text = text.lower()  # приводим все к нижнему регистру

from string import punctuation, whitespace

# Убираем все знаки пунктуации и "невидимые" символы (табы, пробелы и т.д.)
for c in punctuation + whitespace:
    text = text.replace(c, '')

print(text)  # йцукенqwerty

# Дальше словарь только для транслитерации
# (он ровно в 3 раза меньше чем ваш исходный словарь)
alph = {
    "й":"j","ц":"c","у":"u","к":"k","е":"e","н":"n",
    "г":"g","ш":"sh","щ":"shch","з":"z","х":"h","ъ":"",
    "ф":"f","ы":"y","в":"v","а":"a","п":"p","р":"r",
    "о":"o","л":"l","д":"d","ж":"zh","э":"e",
    "я":"ya","ч":"ch","с":"s","м":"m","и":"i",
    "т":"t","ь":"","б":"b","ю":"yu"
}

for c, r in alph.items():
    text = text.replace(c, r)

print(text)  # jcukenqwerty
```

Данную задачу можно решить по-другому: например, первоначальную очистку делать с помощью регулярных выражений, транслитерацию с помощью метода [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.translate), но вам на данный момент для обучения хватит и примера из этого ответа.